# How to solve these equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I tried to solve these two equations by `Solve` function and `Reduce`, but it does not work. Mathematica shuts down! Can anyone help me, please?

```
eq1 = (1500 - 100/Sin[alp])/Sin[180 - alp - th2] == (1176.795 - 100/Tan[alp])/Sin[th2];`
eq2 = 200 Cos[90 - alp - th2] - 500 Sin[alp] == 100;
Solve[{eq1,eq2},alp]
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant `Sin[180 - alp - th2]` and not `Sin[Pi - alp - th2]` and same for `Cos[90 - alp - th2]`.  If you want `90` to be degrees, need to use `90 Degree` or better just use `Pi/2` .

Comment: yes , I meant Pi instead of 180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it gives you what you expect

```
eq1=(1500-100/Sin[alp])/Sin[Pi-alp-th2]==(1176.795-100/Tan[alp])/Sin[th2];
eq2=200 Cos[Pi/2-alp-th2]-500 Sin[alp]==100;
Solve[Rationalize@{eq1,eq2},{alp,th2},Reals]//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks its work , you can use Normal[%] /. {C[1] -> 0 , C[2] -> 0} to remove a conditionalEpression and get a numeral answer